# Difference in rendering dates - IE JavaScript vs. Chrome JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, date

I have the following snippet of JavaScript code I use for rendering a date range from the current month to the same month last year:

```
var today = new Date();
var endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
var startDate = new Date(endDate.getYear() - 1, endDate.getMonth() - 1, 1);
```

In IE 8 it gives me the correct date range:

> Fri Jun 1 00:00:00 MST 2012 - Mon Jul 1 00:00:00 MST 2013

When I run the same code in Chrome, I get the following date range:

> Wed Jun 01 0112 00:00:00 MST - Mon Jul 01 2013 00:00:00 MST

The year for the start date is 0112.  What do I need to do in order to get the correct date range in IE and Chrome?

Comment: "The getYear method returns the year minus 1900" - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *What do I need to do in order to get the correct date range in IE and Chrome?*

Use `getFullYear()` for both `endDate` and `startDate`:

```
var startDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear() - 1, endDate.getMonth() - 1, 1);
```

`getYear()` was intended to return the short year -- `96` for `1996`. But, its behavior varied between browsers for dates with years outside the 1900s.

Specifically, [IE 4 - 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/x0a9sc10.aspx) imitate `getFullYear()` for other years:

> In Internet Explorer 4.0 through Internet Explorer 8 standards mode, the formula depends on the year. For the years 1900 through 1999, the value returned is a 2-digit value that is the stored year minus 1900. For dates outside that range, the 4-digit year is returned. For example, 1996 is returned as 96, but 1825 and 2025 are returned as is.

IE9 returned to the [standardized behavior](http://es5.github.io/#B.2.4) that you're witnessing in Chrome where (pseudo-code):

```
getYear() == getFullYear() - 1900
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation with answer.

Answer (score 2):

getYear is a deprecated function that returns the year minus 1900. You should use getFullYear() instead.